# Logic Remote iPad app no longer able to control Logic Pro X

Tags: macos, ios, ipad, logic

I'm facing an issue with Logic Pro X (on macOS Sierra) and Logic Remote on my iPad. Up until recently, controlling Logic Pro X with the iPad was working perfectly fine, but since a couple of weeks ago (might have been related to an update of either Logic Pro X, or Logic Remote), the mixing controls on the iPad are no longer working.

When I try to change a track's volume on the iPad, nothing happens in Logic Pro X, instead, the track's volume slider on the iPad drops down to zero and can't be moved anymore. This happens with all tracks in all of my Logic Pro X projects. Restarting the MacBook or the iPad has not fixed the issue.

What can I do to get this working again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that deleting the *Logic Remote* device in Logic Pro X's *Control Surface Setup* screen fixes the issue:

- In Logic Pro X, go to *Logic Pro X > Control Surfaces > Setup...*
- Find the device that is representing the iPad's Logic Remote app.
- Right-click the entry and select *Delete*
- Close down the iPad's Logic Remote app and restart it.
- Wait for it to connect to Logic Pro X and the mixing controls will work fine again.

[image: Control Surface Setup]

Answer (score 0):

I followed these steps

You have to have the CS prefs on your Mac.. It is created as soon as you launch Logic Pro.. so again, follow the steps exactly as stated.. Do not try to do it another way..

Also do the same for the com.apple.logic10.plist which is the correct file name.. for Logic's own prefs.. (The one you tried to use previously was for earlier versions of Logic...)

Make sure you have quit Logic before doing these actions...

You will then find those specific files ..... and you can delete them...

Deleting the prefs and CS prefs file removes all Controller info that Logic uses....

Remember also, to now restart your Mac.......

Now launch LPX and both new Prefs and CS prefs will be created....

Now test....

And now I cannot add any new control surfaces to logic help

Comment: there is no longer any control surface setup

Comment: It may help others more to provide the path where these files are located, and explain what they do. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this will help someone.

I did this:

While Logic Remote was connected, I inserted the Lighting wire, when everything was connected, I removed it and everything continued to work over Wi-Fi without a wire.

Apparently this problem is access to the device, you can make a fix.

Comment: English only please. I have used Google translate to suggest an edit for you